Did the fire and sulfur that rained on the inhabitants of Sodom source from hell
Was the fire and sulfur that rained on the inhabitants of Sodom from hell? It seems as if God opened a portal in the sky and allowed the fire to rain on the inhabitants of Sodom and Gomorrah directly from hell and that is the reason why the angels asked them not to look back?
Could this be since both the fire mentioned in the book of Genesis and the one on Revelation burn with sulfur?
Genesis 19:24

Then the LORD rained on Sodom and Gomorrah sulfur and fire from the LORD out of heaven.

Revelation 20:10

and the devil who had deceived them was thrown into the lake of fire and sulfur where the beast and the false prophet were

It seems as if the inhabitants of Sodom are the first human beings to experience hell and they do it here on earth as they already judged, did the fire source from hell?

If the fire that burned Sodom was from hell, then hell is in heaven!!  See Gen 19:24.  The fire was NOT from hell but HEAVEN.

@Dottard but hell is not so far from heaven as people are judged in heaven and thrown into the lake of fire which means the target of the throw event is not so far

Gehenna has not yet been kindled. (The stars have not yet fallen to the earth in the conflagration at the end of time which results in a lake of fire.) Whether volcanic lava or comet or otherwise, the source is not identified. It came from heavenwards as Divine judgment is what should be uppermost in the mind.

@NigelJ, so this means hell fire consumes and destroys all souls and there is no eternal torment for if the in habitats of Sodom perished as a result

@DongLi No, that does not follow at all. Scripture is very clear on this matter. 'The smoke of their torment rises up for ever and ever and they have no rest, day nor night' and like passages . . . . .

@NigelJ, that refers to the evil triad ie the devil, the antichrist and the false prophet. They are tormented day and night but Jesus said both the body and the soul will be destroyed in hell

@NjgelJ, the fires of hell cannot harm Satan like men because he is made from fire, he was a cherubim or a seraphim but he is a fire spirit. He refused to worship Adam alongside other angels who felt they are better than Adam. God's will of having the angelic host bow down to man was still established through Christ who is worshipped in heaven right now and he is a man.

See my answer to What is the archaeological evidence for Sodom and Gomorrah? - Christianity.SE, and Beyond Today' magazine's January–February 2022 issue for related recent archæological discoveries.

Nomenclature
In the English Bible "Hell" refers to Hades/Sheol, a place under the earth where (at least prior to the resurrection) almost everybody's spirit went at death.
The lake of fire is expected to be other than on earth, although Nigel J suggests that when the Earth is destroyed, the Earth will be converted into the lake of fire. The lake of fire is sometimes referred to allegorically as Gehenna, the Jerusalem trash dump, where fire did burn continually.
Hades/Sheol
There is no reason to think that God took fire and sulfur from Hades to rain on Sodom and Gomorrah. But that isn't what you were asking.
The Lake of Fire
God can do whatever He pleases, but He has a much closer source of fire and sulfur, if the lake of fire even exists already. Lava tends to smell like sulfur. He could easily have had a volcano provide the fire and sulfur.
Some say we shouldn't look for natural explanations for God's miracles, but they increase my faith by showing that they aren't made up. These include the flood, the asteroid of Bethlehem and the parting of the Red Sea.
